# how to group by partial string of the column in the linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am intended to use the LINQ to group the date column, since the date column is the DateTime format, so I am unable to group by this column. In the end , I need to group by the partial value of the date time so I can generate my report based on the date. This is what I have tried.

```
var query = from data in entities.sales_order
            where data.status == "Completed" || data.status == "Shipped"
            group data by data.created_date.Value.ToString("ddMMyyyy") into g
            select new { dateKey = g.Key, dataList = g.ToList() };
```

but in the end LINQ does not accept the `ToString()`(Substring) method in the query.

May I know how to solve this problem?

if i execute this i will get this error[image]

if i dont include the ToString("ddMMyyyy") the code running fine

Comment: you don't have `Substring` method in your sample. What you mean by _LINQ does not accept_? Did you get an exception or compiler error?

Comment: Are you getting any error? where you used `Substring` in the above query

Comment: Please clarify your question. First, there is no `Substring` method in the query. Second, it's a valid *general* LINQ query. If you target a specific query provider (like Entity Framework), then specify it.

Comment: sorry all, i edited my question, tostring is consider as cut the partial of the string so in the end it return me the error

Comment: What type of `data.created_date.Value`? If it `string` then you cannot use `DateTime` formats for "substring" of string

Comment: @Fabio the column type is date time

Comment: @AndersonPimentel i checked, the value is not null

Comment: It's not a LINQ issue, but an Entity Framework one. It says so right in the exception message. Why would you want to call ToString on your date? Can you not just group by date, or by `date.Date`? Edit: fix property name.

Comment: can't you just group it on `data.created_date.Date`

Comment: To expand on this further, this particular exception gets thrown when your LINQ query involves something Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate into a SQL query. In this case, it's ToString called on your DateTime object.

Comment: @DaveBecker ur logic is right but when i try i get this

Comment: Additional information: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.